# Laravel-5 Foreach in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Please help me, i want to display foreach value in blade, how to display foreach in foreach ?

```
 {!!Form::select('subkategori', array(
    @foreach($sktgr as $kategori=>$value)
         "$kategori" => array(
         @foreach($sktgr as $kategori=>$value)
         "{{$sub}}",
         @endforeach
         ),
    @endforeach
    ),"$course->idSubkategori",['style'=>'width:100%','data-toggle'=>'select2'])!!}
```

Comment: done, my problem solved , {!!Form::select('subkategori',$sktgr,['style'=>'width:100%','data-toggle'=>'select2'])!!}

Comment: post it as answer and mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem

```
{!! Form::select('subkategori',$sktgr,['style'=>'width:100%','data-toggle'=>'sele‌​ct2']) !!}
```